# Noise while writing and reading an image (MNIST)

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have been working on Handwritten Digit Recognition, I wanted to save the MNIST image and read it again and convert to its array in order to feed the CNN.

The logic is that if i am able to read-recognise these images correctly..i can use the same function for my real inputs.

**CODE 1 :**

```
def create_images():
    for a in range(1):
        num_test = 7885
        image= data.test.images[num_test]
        plot_image(image)
        pixels = 255 * (1.0 - image)
        pixels.resize((28,28))
        im = Image.fromarray(pixels.astype(np.uint8), mode='L')
        im.save("2.jpeg")
```

Corresponding output :

[image: MNIST IMAGE]

**CODE 2 :**

```
def ImagetoArray(image):
    im = Image.open(image)
    tv = list(im.getdata()) 
    # normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
    tva = [(255 - x) * 1.0 / 255.0 for x in tv]
    tva = np.asarray(tva)
    count=0
    #plot_image(tva)
    return tva
```

Corresponding Output:

[image: Read Image]

While i know the noise seems very negligible, but the images are only 28X28 pixels and the noise may interfere.

I wanted to know from where the noise is being added and how to overcome it ? 
Does using opencv make any difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use JPEG. Use PNG or TIFF for lossless image compression.

The noise is added by the lossy compression of the JPEG algorithm.